ошибка в telebot retrieve_data
пишу бота на telebot.
Недавно узнал про функцию bot.retrieve_data и начал внедрять её в код, но в последствии она перестала работать и выдаёт в ошибке только id пользователя. Не могу понять в чём дело.
async def delInf(message):
async with bot.retrieve_data(
    message.from_user.id,
    message.chat.id
    ) as a:
    a["numberOfFile"] = 0
    a["numberOfAllFiles"] = 0
    a["listOfFileNames"] = {}

Ошибка: (async_telebot.py:565 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "(id пользователя)"

Я нашёл в чём была проблема. Перед использованием retrieve_data нужно чтобы был назначен какой ни-будь set_state, а если retrieve_data несколько раз в одной функции, то set_state должен быть между ними.
async def run(message):
await set_state(
    message.from_user.id,
    program.hello,
    message.chat.id
    )
await delInf(message)

async def delInf(message):
async with bot.retrieve_data(
    message.from_user.id,
    message.chat.id
    ) as a:
    a["numberOfFile"] = 0
    a["numberOfAllFiles"] = 0
    a["listOfFileNames"] = {}

